# Admin guard login, The email field is required, Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-validation, laravel-authentication, laravel-guard

Previously it worked before I edit it for firebase, but for now I want to see local auth first after I edit it for firebase. it can register but not login, it resulted in **The email field is required.** it is what resulted in either normal user login or admin guard login.

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/admin',[LoginController::class,'showAdminLoginForm'])->name('admin.login-view');
Route::post('/admin',[LoginController::class,'adminLogin'])->name('admin.login');
```

**LoginController.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Session;
use Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Admin;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
protected $auth;
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->firebaseAuth = $firebaseAuth;
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
        //$this->auth =app("firebase.auth");
    }
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
public function showAdminLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login', ['url' => route('admin.login-view'), 'title'=>'Admin']);
    }

    public function adminLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if (\Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only(['email','password']), $request->get('remember'))){
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        }

        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="login" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                {{ __('Username or Email') }}
                            </label>
                        
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="login" type="text"
                                    class="form-control{{ $errors->has('username') || $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                    name="login" value="{{ old('username') ?: old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                        
                                @if ($errors->has('username') || $errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') ?: $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
```

So what went wrong that I get **The email field is required**? Before I edit it for firebase it working perfectly in local.

**Solved**

Change `name="login"` into `name="email"` and change `route('login')` into `route('admin.login')` in login blade, it seems my error stems from difference routing and what's required in login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you have defined validation for `email` field is required but in your form in blade file you have named field as `login`. That's why in controller, email value is not found.

Change the field name from `name="login"` to `name="email"`.

Comment: now it is These credentials do not match our records.

Comment: That means either credentials are wrong or you have stored the password as a simple string in your database instead of storing the ``hashed`` value. ``attempt()`` method of the ``Auth`` facade verifies the entered password with a hashed value. so make sure to store the password after hashing it.

Comment: Also, his routes goes "login" it should be "admin.login"

Comment: Please don't code-format normal text.

Comment: Oh, thanks. For your information, my password already in hashed value... it seems my error stems from routing error. As the program tries to login via users rather than admins.

Answer (score 0):

its because your blade try to submit the login parameter instead of email parameter

you can fix it by :

```
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'login'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if (\Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only(['login','password']), $request->get('remember'))){
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        }

        return back()->withInput($request->only('login', 'remember'));
    }
```

Comment: got 'The email field is required' so this isn't the answer.